# Vista CSHTML en C#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, cshtml

Estoy trabajando con una vista CSHTML, solamente tengo una duda con un fragmento de código que se me fue dado:

```
@*<button type="button" class="bel-btn bel-btn-default bel-btn-default-active"
                 onclick="location.href='@Url.Action("IndexCiudad", "Ciudad")'">
           Vista Previa
</button>*@
```

Mi duda es con el evento onclick, ¿en estos casos a que se suele hacer referencia en los parámetros IndexCiudad, Ciudad?, ¿Hace referencia a algún controlador o clase que pueda tener dentro del proyecto?. Es lo único a lo que no termino de entender a este código que se me fue dado como guía.

Para agregar, estoy trabajando con la carga de un archivo en Excel, ya realice el controlador, clases que contienen columnas y estas mismas ya las agregue dentro de mi vista. Mi fin es solo entender lo que va dentro del evento onclick.

Comment: El metodo Url.Action te devuelve el metodo que tengas dentro de un controlador, en ese caso sería el metodo IndexCiudad del controlador Ciudad

Comment: Yo quitaría el onclick y solo pondría una `<a>` y dentro el url.action

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Url.Action generar una url con los parámetros que le pasas. En tu caso se esta pasando la acción "IndexCiudad", que está en el controller "CiudadController", la palabra controller se omite en el método action, por eso pusieron "Ciudad".

https://learn.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/api/system.web.mvc.urlhelper.action?view=aspnet-mvc-5.2

Saludos.

Comment: Tu respuesta podría mejorarse con información de apoyo adicional. Por favor, pulsa en [edit] para añadir más detalles, como citas o documentación, para que otros puedan confirmar que tu respuesta es correcta. Puedes encontrar más información sobre cómo escribir buenas respuestas [en el centro de ayuda](/help/how-to-answer).